# why this response from solr is not correct

Tags: javascript, solr

I make a request to solr and i want to find all the records in biz_subject column that start with this string - `myel` but when i tested this query  I found that solr gives me some records in which `myel` is in the middle or at the end! and i don't want that.

for example when i search for `evn` the response should be `evno`, `evniiiii` and so on and the response also gives `limevnii`, `kisuevn` and i don't want those.

```
function triming()
{
   k++;
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
   { 
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
        {
           alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
           var  str = xmlhttp.responseText;
           var rsp = JSON.parse(str);

           var object;
           alert (rsp.response.numFound);
           //Pin marker on the maps
           for( var i = 0; i < rsp.response.numFound; i++) 
           {
              object = rsp.response.docs[i];
           }
           alert (rsp.response.docs[1].biz_subject);
            //title: object.biz_subject,                
        }
    }


    var url = "http://localhost:8983/solr/db/select?q=biz_subject:" + encodeURIComponent(newstr)+"*&wt=json&indent=true";
    //  alert (url);
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send(); 
  }
```

**schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->

<!--  
 This is the Solr schema file. This file should be named "schema.xml" and
 should be in the conf directory under the solr home
 (i.e. ./solr/conf/schema.xml by default) 
 or located where the classloader for the Solr webapp can find it.

 This example schema is the recommended starting point for users.
 It should be kept correct and concise, usable out-of-the-box.

 For more information, on how to customize this file, please see
 http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml
-->

<schema name="db" version="1.1">
  <!-- attribute "name" is the name of this schema and is only used for display purposes.
       Applications should change this to reflect the nature of the search collection.
       version="1.1" is Solr's version number for the schema syntax and semantics.  It should
       not normally be changed by applications.
       1.0: multiValued attribute did not exist, all fields are multiValued by nature
       1.1: multiValued attribute introduced, false by default -->

  <types>
    <!-- field type definitions. The "name" attribute is
       just a label to be used by field definitions.  The "class"
       attribute and any other attributes determine the real
       behavior of the fieldType.
         Class names starting with "solr" refer to java classes in the
       org.apache.solr.analysis package.
    -->
    <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
    <!-- The StrField type is not analyzed, but indexed/stored verbatim.  
       - StrField and TextField support an optional compressThreshold which
       limits compression (if enabled in the derived fields) to values which
       exceed a certain size (in characters).
    -->
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

    <!-- boolean type: "true" or "false" -->
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

    <!-- The optional sortMissingLast and sortMissingFirst attributes are
         currently supported on types that are sorted internally as strings.
       - If sortMissingLast="true", then a sort on this field will cause documents
         without the field to come after documents with the field,
         regardless of the requested sort order (asc or desc).
       - If sortMissingFirst="true", then a sort on this field will cause documents
         without the field to come before documents with the field,
         regardless of the requested sort order.
       - If sortMissingLast="false" and sortMissingFirst="false" (the default),
         then default lucene sorting will be used which places docs without the
         field first in an ascending sort and last in a descending sort.
    -->    


    <!-- numeric field types that store and index the text
         value verbatim (and hence don't support range queries, since the
         lexicographic ordering isn't equal to the numeric ordering) -->
    <fieldType name="integer" class="solr.IntField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.LongField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.FloatField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.DoubleField" omitNorms="true"/>


    <!-- Numeric field types that manipulate the value into
         a string value that isn't human-readable in its internal form,
         but with a lexicographic ordering the same as the numeric ordering,
         so that range queries work correctly. -->
    <fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="slong" class="solr.SortableLongField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sfloat" class="solr.SortableFloatField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sdouble" class="solr.SortableDoubleField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>


    <!-- The format for this date field is of the form 1995-12-31T23:59:59Z, and
         is a more restricted form of the canonical representation of dateTime
         http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime    
         The trailing "Z" designates UTC time and is mandatory.
         Optional fractional seconds are allowed: 1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z
         All other components are mandatory.

         Expressions can also be used to denote calculations that should be
         performed relative to "NOW" to determine the value, ie...

               NOW/HOUR
                  ... Round to the start of the current hour
               NOW-1DAY
                  ... Exactly 1 day prior to now
               NOW/DAY+6MONTHS+3DAYS
                  ... 6 months and 3 days in the future from the start of
                      the current day

         Consult the DateField javadocs for more information.
      -->
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.DateField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>


    <!-- The "RandomSortField" is not used to store or search any
         data.  You can declare fields of this type it in your schema
         to generate psuedo-random orderings of your docs for sorting 
         purposes.  The ordering is generated based on the field name 
         and the version of the index, As long as the index version
         remains unchanged, and the same field name is reused,
         the ordering of the docs will be consistent.  
         If you want differend psuedo-random orderings of documents,
         for the same version of the index, use a dynamicField and
         change the name
     -->
    <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" />

    <!-- solr.TextField allows the specification of custom text analyzers
         specified as a tokenizer and a list of token filters. Different
         analyzers may be specified for indexing and querying.

         The optional positionIncrementGap puts space between multiple fields of
         this type on the same document, with the purpose of preventing false phrase
         matching across fields.

         For more info on customizing your analyzer chain, please see
         http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters
     -->

    <!-- One can also specify an existing Analyzer class that has a
         default constructor via the class attribute on the analyzer element
    <fieldType name="text_greek" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.el.GreekAnalyzer"/>
    </fieldType>
    -->

    <!-- A text field that only splits on whitespace for exact matching of words -->
    <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- A text field that uses WordDelimiterFilter to enable splitting and matching of
        words on case-change, alpha numeric boundaries, and non-alphanumeric chars,
        so that a query of "wifi" or "wi fi" could match a document containing "Wi-Fi".
        Synonyms and stopwords are customized by external files, and stemming is enabled.
        Duplicate tokens at the same position (which may result from Stemmed Synonyms or
        WordDelim parts) are removed.
        -->
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>


    <!-- Less flexible matching, but less false matches.  Probably not ideal for product names,
         but may be good for SKUs.  Can insert dashes in the wrong place and still match. -->
    <fieldType name="textTight" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- This is an example of using the KeywordTokenizer along
         With various TokenFilterFactories to produce a sortable field
         that does not include some properties of the source text
      -->
    <fieldType name="alphaOnlySort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer>
        <!-- KeywordTokenizer does no actual tokenizing, so the entire
             input string is preserved as a single token
          -->
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- The LowerCase TokenFilter does what you expect, which can be
             when you want your sorting to be case insensitive
          -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <!-- The TrimFilter removes any leading or trailing whitespace -->
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        <!-- The PatternReplaceFilter gives you the flexibility to use
             Java Regular expression to replace any sequence of characters
             matching a pattern with an arbitrary replacement string, 
             which may include back refrences to portions of the orriginal
             string matched by the pattern.

             See the Java Regular Expression documentation for more
             infomation on pattern and replacement string syntax.

             http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html
          -->
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
                pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"
        />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- since fields of this type are by default not stored or indexed, any data added to 
         them will be ignored outright 
     --> 
    <fieldtype name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" class="solr.StrField" /> 

 </types>


 <fields>
   <!-- Valid attributes for fields:
     name: mandatory - the name for the field
     type: mandatory - the name of a previously defined type from the <types> section
     indexed: true if this field should be indexed (searchable or sortable)
     stored: true if this field should be retrievable
     compressed: [false] if this field should be stored using gzip compression
       (this will only apply if the field type is compressable; among
       the standard field types, only TextField and StrField are)
     multiValued: true if this field may contain multiple values per document
     omitNorms: (expert) set to true to omit the norms associated with
       this field (this disables length normalization and index-time
       boosting for the field, and saves some memory).  Only full-text
       fields or fields that need an index-time boost need norms.
     termVectors: [false] set to true to store the term vector for a given field.
       When using MoreLikeThis, fields used for similarity should be stored for 
       best performance.
   -->

   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
   <field name="**biz_subject**" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="company_name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
   <field name="obshtina" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="role" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="country" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="nace_code" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="nace_text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="main_office_town" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="zip_code" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="address" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="phone" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="fax" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="email" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="web" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="rid" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="location" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

   <!-- "default" values can be specified for fields, indicating which
        value should be used if no value is specified when adding a document.
     -->
<!--
   <field name="egn" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" default="0"/>
   <field name="fn" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
-->

   <!-- Some sample docs exists solely to demonstrate the spellchecker
        functionality, this is the only field they container.
        Typically you might build the spellchecker of "catchall" type field
        containing all of the text in each document
     -->
   <field name="word" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>


   <!-- catchall field, containing all other searchable text fields (implemented
        via copyField further on in this schema  -->
   <field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

   <!-- non-tokenized version of manufacturer to make it easier to sort or group
        results by manufacturer.  copied from "manu" via copyField -->
   <field name="manu_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

   <!-- Here, default is used to create a "timestamp" field indicating
        When each document was indexed.
     -->
   <field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>


   <!-- Dynamic field definitions.  If a field name is not found, dynamicFields
        will be used if the name matches any of the patterns.
        RESTRICTION: the glob-like pattern in the name attribute must have
        a "*" only at the start or the end.
        EXAMPLE:  name="*_i" will match any field ending in _i (like myid_i, z_i)
        Longer patterns will be matched first.  if equal size patterns
        both match, the first appearing in the schema will be used.  -->
   <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="sint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="slong"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="sfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="sdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_coordinate" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="random*" type="random" />

   <!-- uncomment the following to ignore any fields that don't already match an existing 
        field name or dynamic field, rather than reporting them as an error. 
        alternately, change the type="ignored" to some other type e.g. "text" if you want 
        unknown fields indexed and/or stored by default --> 
   <!--dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" multiValued="true" /-->

 </fields>

 <!-- Field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. 
      Unless this field is marked with required="false", it will be a required field
   -->
 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

 <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
 <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>

 <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
 <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>

  <!-- copyField commands copy one field to another at the time a document
        is added to the index.  It's used either to index the same field differently,
        or to add multiple fields to the same field for easier/faster searching.  -->
   <copyField source="id" dest="rid"/>
<!--
   <copyField source="cat" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="name" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="name" dest="nameSort"/>
   <copyField source="name" dest="alphaNameSort"/>
   <copyField source="manu" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="features" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="includes" dest="text"/>

   <copyField source="manu" dest="manu_exact"/>
-->

 <!-- Similarity is the scoring routine for each document vs. a query.
      A custom similarity may be specified here, but the default is fine
      for most applications.  -->
 <!-- <similarity class="org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.DefaultSimilarity"/> -->

</schema>
```

Comment: Can you add the fieldType and its definition in your schema.xml for the field `biz_subject`? Also give examples of correct and incorrect matches.

Comment: Hello i have done this! if you want you can see my schema!

Comment: So the type of `biz_subject` is `text`. I can't see why it returns matches like `limevnii` for a search on `evn*`. What you can try yourself is use the analysis tool at `http://HOST:PORT/solr/CORE/analysis` and enter `limevnii` in 'Field Value (Index)' and see what tokens are generated during analysis time, which should help you debug.

Comment: can it be something related with that I use utf -8 characters - the bulgarian alphabet - for example when i write шик it returns ил шик or нес -шик. so it finks that ил шик are two words. Thank you arun for the help - if you have something in mind please write!

Comment: Why do you have your field defined as "\*\*biz_subject\*\*" or is this just an artifact of stackoverflow markup?

Comment: I guess that was done manually just to highlight the field :-)

Comment: Try to switch field type for your biz_subject field from text to text_ws or textTight (don't forget to reindex). This could be caused by splitOnCaseChange option of WordDelimiterFilterFactory (if you have limEnvii) or english porter stemming (not sure). You should also look into http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Bulgarian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can make the fieldType of `biz_subject` string. Or if you need it to be `text` for other search purposes, then create a new [copy field](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) of `biz_subject` named `biz_subject_str` whose type is string. Then you can perform a wild-card search on your search term like

```
q=biz_subject:evn*
```

or

```
q=biz_subject_str:evn*
```

Strings are not split into tokens during indexing, so you should not get `limevnii` as a match.